# file not behaving as it should, permission problems

Tags: macos, permission, acl

I cannot delete or move a file owned by me which I have read write permissions. Could anybody help me figure out why? The file is owned by me in group staff and perms are set to 644. The file is located in my home directory it is a single jpg file, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -leO`, (that's a capital O not a zero) please?

Comment: I don't suppose there's any chance you could perhaps label your question as... answered? If its too much to ask, I completely understand. Who has time for these things?

Comment: ye not a problem, just I dont know how to?

Comment: there's a check button tp the left of my answer... press that and it marks your question as answered. and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fire up Terminal and check the file

```
 ls -leO  (that's a capital O not a zero)
```

and if the `uappnd` flag is set, try

```
 chflags nouappnd a.single.jpg
```